# Why doesn't my XPath expression find a newly added node in an XML document?

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I try to add a new node to an XML (svg) document, but when I try to query it afterwards with an XPath expression, it does not find the new node.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $svg = $parser->load_xml(string => <<'SVG');
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape">
<g inkscape:groupmode="layer" id="old-id" inkscape:label="old-label">...</g>
</svg>
SVG

my $layer = XML::LibXML::Element->new('g');     # same result with 'svg:g'
$layer->setAttribute('inkscape:groupmode', 'layer');
$layer->setAttribute('id', 'new-id');
$layer->setAttribute('inkscape:label', 'new-label');
$svg->documentElement()->appendChild($layer);

print "Dump:\n$svg\n";

print "Xpath:\n";
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($svg);
$xpc->registerNs('svg', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
my $xpath = '//svg:g';
foreach my $node ($xpc->findnodes($xpath)) {
    print $node->getAttribute('id'), ": ", $node->getAttribute('inkscape:label'), "\n";
}
```

This prints:

```
Dump:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape">
<g inkscape:groupmode="layer" id="old-id" inkscape:label="old-label">initially</g>
<g inkscape:groupmode="layer" inkscape:label="new-label" id="new-id"/></svg>

Xpath:
old-id: old-label
```

The new node shows up when I dump the whole xml document, but the XPath expression only reports the old node.

Why is that and how do I get the XPath expression to also find the newly added node?

Comment: Perhaps you need to create the element like this: `$root = $dom->documentElement();
$dom->setDocumentElement( $root );
$element = $dom->createElement( $nodename );`, then  append. The element is created within the document but not yet assigned anywhere.From [here](https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/view/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your print statement is outputting XML that, if reparsed, would give you the correct result, your in-memory DOM doesn't have awareness of the namespace of the new element. To tell the new element about the namespaces, we can use `SetNamespace` and `SetAttributeNS` per the [docs](https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/view/lib/XML/LibXML/Element.pod)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $svg = $parser->load_xml(string => <<'SVG');
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape">
<g inkscape:groupmode="layer" id="old-id" inkscape:label="old-label">...</g>
</svg>
SVG

my $layer = XML::LibXML::Element->new('g');     # same result with 'svg:g'
$layer->setNamespace('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
$layer->setNamespace('http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape', 'inkscape', 0);
$layer->setAttributeNS('http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape', 'groupmode', 'layer');
$layer->setAttribute('id', 'new-id');
$layer->setAttributeNS('http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape', 'label', 'new-label');
$svg->documentElement()->appendChild($layer);

print "Dump:\n$svg\n";

print "Xpath:\n";
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($svg);
$xpc->registerNs('svg', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
my $xpath = '//svg:g';
foreach my $node ($xpc->findnodes($xpath)) {
    print $node->getAttribute('id'), ": ", $node->getAttribute('inkscape:label'), "\n";
}
```

Output

```
Dump:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape">
<g inkscape:groupmode="layer" id="old-id" inkscape:label="old-label">...</g>
<g inkscape:groupmode="layer" id="new-id" inkscape:label="new-label"/></svg>

Xpath:
old-id: old-label
new-id: new-label
```